# Crash Recovery of Data Strcutrues in C++ Appication

Tags: c++, serialization, crash, recovery

I have a C++ application which process network packets at high data rate.
This application has various data structures (STL maps/list etc) maintaining application state. These data structures are updated frequently.
Input to this application is error prone thus making it vulnerable to crashes.

What I want to do is to save application state (various data structures) to persistent media in order to regain it after crash. 
Is there any framework/library/practice which can help me in achieving the same.

Requesting you to not direct this thread to 'remove vulnerability to crashes'.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Restart and Recovery framework](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2011/03/21/windows-restart-and-recovery-recipe.aspx) recipe by Kate Gregory.  It's a video that explains how to employ this strategy.  Also, take a look at [Application Recovery and Restart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc948909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for reference.  I've used and modified this recipe and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding

> Input to this application is error prone thus making it vulnerable to crashes

No, input should never cause the application to crash<sup>*</sup>. It's not the input that's error prone. It's the application.

About the only you can do if you really want the information to persist, is to persist it in the first place, *before* each crash.

A crash predictor could of course come in handy for that.

But the general notion is just, persist what you need to be persisted, before a crash makes it practically impossible to do so.

In the crashed state you **can not rely on anything** inside the application.

Saving information in that state would at the very least require extensive verification at the point of use of that stored info.

In short,

- the best is to fix the bugs, but
- failing that, as interim measure you can persist info as it becomes available (*before* crashes), but then
- with the aim of reimplementing the whole shebang from scratch, which I recommend.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>: Unless it's desgined for that, of course.</sub>

Comment: By error prone input I mean following -
'This application performs DPI wherein it involves network-application/protocol layer parsing. There are various scenarios under which input cannot be predicted (e.g. change in specification of applications-packets, non compliance to standards, proprietary protocols, transmission errors, bug in network-applications etc.)'